# styleClass is not working in PrimeNg Dialog?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to add the styleClass in primeNg but it is not working

Html file

```
<p-dialog [(header)]="dialogText" [(visible)]="displayDlg" [modal]="true" [responsive]="true" 
  styleClass='pDialog' >
```

CSS File

```
.pDialog{
width:700px;
overflow: visible;
}
```

Instead I wrote the `contentStyle` this is working

```
<p-dialog [(header)]="dialogText" [(visible)]="displayDlg" [modal]="true" [responsive]="true" 
   [contentStyle]="{'width': '700px','overflow':'visible'}">
```

How to make it in the css file?

Answer (score 2):

You can override prime-ng css by using `ng:deep`

```
:host ::ng-deep {
     .pDialog{
         width:700px;
         overflow: visible;
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried with this width is working but `overflow: visible` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add 'encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None' in your component like this;

```
@Component({
...
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

})